# SHA256 mismatch trying to brew wine

Tags: homebrew, electron, wine, electron-builder

I'm trying to `brew install wine` as a step in getting [electron-builder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-builder) working. But all I can get is this response:

> ==> Installing dependencies for wine: libusb-compat, fontconfig, xz, libtiff, webp, gd, libgphoto2, little-cms2, jasper, libicns, makedepend, openssl, sane-backends, libtasn1, gmp, ne
>   ==> Installing wine dependency: libusb-compat
>   ==> Downloading https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/libusb/libusb-compat-0.1/libusb-compat-0.1.5/libusb-compat-0.1.5.tar.bz2
>   ==> Downloading from http://downloads.sourceforge.net/#!/project/libusb/libusb-compat-0.1/libusb-compat-0.1.5/libusb-compat-0.1.5.tar.bz2
>
> ################################################################## 100.0%
>
> Error: SHA256 mismatch
>   Expected: 404ef4b6b324be79ac1bfb3d839eac860fbc929e6acb1ef88793a6ea328bc55a
>   Actual: 818a4b8bbcb50878a8b1b9f71b4274d242ab46bf860c74676e98dec1d0248821 
>   Archive: /Users/nicholasstephan/Library/Caches/Homebrew/libusb-compat-0.1.5.tar.bz2
>   To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.

I've tried some of the obvious solutions:

Removing the `libusb-compat-0.1.5.tar.bz2` file it suggests I remove, but I just get the same result.

I've tried to `brew cleanup` and `brew update`, to no effect.

What could be going wrong here? What is an SHA256?

Comment: _"trying to brew wine"_ 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like sourceforge has some issues according to this brew issue at github:

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/2952

So I think the best is in this case to wait. As I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is back working now.

Had the exact same issue: installing Wine for electron builder and got the SHA mismatch yesterday.
Deleted the libusb-compat-0.1.5.tar.bz2 file and tried again just now and all works fine here.